# Django y Python, ¿Cómo guardar datos de formulario y a su vez obtener datos de los modelos?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

Tengo mis modelos, vistas, urls, y lo que estoy intentando hacer, es realizar un save de un formulario, en eso no hay problemas, pero la verdad desconozco alguna forma de al momento de guardar los datos recibidos del html, que consulte y guarde según la condición los datos que faltan en mi modelo evento.

`Modelos`

```
class Conductor(models.Model):
    nro_personal = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=250)
    rut_persona = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cod_operador = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    nombre_completo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    cod_nivel_cargo = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    desc_nivel_cargo = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    ciod_convenio = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    desc_convenio = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    gerencia_trabajador = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    grupo_de_gasto = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    posicion = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    texto_posicion = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    funcion = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    texto_funcion = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    ce_costo = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    texto_ceco = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    cod_sub_div_pers = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    sub_div_personal = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    area_de_nomina = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    fecha_contrato = models.DateField(default=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'conductor'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nro_personal + " #" + self.cod_operador
    
    def getNombreCompleto(self):
        return self.nombre_completo
    
    def getTiempoContrato(self):
        tiempo = date.today() - self.fecha_contrato
        if tiempo.days <= 365.25:
            if tiempo.days <= 31:
                if tiempo.days == 1:
                    return '1 dia'
                else:
                    return str(tiempo.days) + ' dias'
            else:
                if math.trunc(tiempo.days / 31) == 1:
                    return '1 mes'
                else:
                    return str(math.trunc(tiempo.days / 31)) + ' meses'
        else:
            if math.trunc(tiempo.days / 365.25) == 1:
                return '1 año'
            else:
                return str(math.trunc(tiempo.days / 365.25)) + ' años' 

class Bus(models.Model):
    interno = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patente = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    anio = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    chasis = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    plazas = models.IntegerField()
    carroceria = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patio_antes = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patio_actual = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # fecha_distribucion = models.DateField(null=True)
    # estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'bus'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.interno) + " " + self.patente

class Evento(models.Model):

    class Responsabilidad:
        OPER = 'O'
        VAND = 'V'
        MTTO = 'M'

        CHOICES = [
            (OPER, 'Operaciones'),
            (VAND, 'Vandalismo'),
            (MTTO, 'Mantenimiento'),
        ]

    class Clasificacion:
        LEVE = 'L'
        INTERMEDIO = 'I'
        GRAVE = 'G'
        NO_MTTO = 'N'

        CHOICES = [
            (LEVE, 'Leve'),
            (INTERMEDIO, 'Intermedio'),
            (GRAVE, 'Grave'),
            (NO_MTTO, 'No Mantenimiento')
        ]
    
    class EstadoMTTO:
        EN_MTTO = 'E'
        EN_MTTO_DET = 'F'
        PEND_EN_MTTO = 'G'
        PEND_EN_MTTO_DET = 'H'
        REPARADO = 'R'
        REPARADO_DET = 'S'
        NO_DISP = 'N'

        CHOICES = [
            (EN_MTTO, 'En Mantenimiento'),
            (EN_MTTO_DET, 'En mantenimiento con Reincidencia'),
            (PEND_EN_MTTO, 'Pendiente de Aprobacion'),
            (PEND_EN_MTTO_DET, 'Pendiente Aprobacion de Mtto'),
            (REPARADO, 'Reparado'),
            (REPARADO_DET, 'Reparado con Reincidencia'),
            (NO_DISP, 'No disponible'),
        ]

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fecha_hora_suceso = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    responsabilidad = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Responsabilidad.CHOICES, default=Responsabilidad.OPER)
    clasificacion = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Clasificacion.CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    necesita_mtto = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    graffiti = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    estado_mtto = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=EstadoMTTO.CHOICES, default=EstadoMTTO.EN_MTTO)
    tabla = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    recorrido = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    declarado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sin_codigo = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    #Fk
    cod_operador = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    nombre_completo = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    texto_posicion = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    area_de_nomina = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    fecha_contrato =  models.DateField(null=True)
    patente = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    #FK
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    patio_actual = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    usuario_registro = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    #FK

    # Foreign Keys
    conductor = models.ForeignKey(Conductor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    determinacion = models.OneToOneField(Determinacion, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    patio = models.ForeignKey(Patio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    solicitud_rrhh = models.OneToOneField(SolicitudRRHH, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    ultima_reparacion = models.OneToOneField(Reparacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'evento'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def days_within_decl(self):
        ################### SWIP TZ ################################
        return abs(datetime.utcnow() - self.fecha_hora_suceso.replace(tzinfo=None)).days

    def count_reparaciones(self, contador, reparacion):
        if reparacion.reparacion_anterior:
            contador = self.count_reparaciones(contador + 1, reparacion.reparacion_anterior)
        return contador

    def total_reparaciones(self):
        contador = 0
        
        if self.ultima_reparacion:
            contador = self.count_reparaciones(contador + 1, self.ultima_reparacion)
        
        return contador
```

Si se pueden fijar en el modelo evento, tengo algunos datos de conductor y bus, y quiero obtener datos de ambos y guardarlos en evento, claro con un trigger sería bueno, pero estuve intentando igual, pero....
¿Existe alguna forma de realizar ese método?, ¿Alguna idea?.
Se los Agradecería muchisimo.

`Vistas`

```
@login_required(login_url="iniciar_sesion")
def registrar_evento(request, interno):
    params = Parameters(request)
    
    if params.getUsuario().patio.nombre == models.Bus.objects.get(interno=interno).patio_actual.upper():
        conductores = simplejson.dumps(list(models.Conductor.objects.all().values('nro_personal', 'cod_operador', 'nombre_completo','genero','texto_posicion','area_de_nomina','fecha_contrato',)), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        params.add('conductores', conductores)

        params.add('bus', models.Bus.objects.get(interno=interno))
        

        tabla_reg = "" if request.POST.get("tabla_reg") == None else request.POST.get("tabla_reg")
        tabla_cod = "" if request.POST.get("tabla_cod") == None else request.POST.get("tabla_cod") 
        tabla_linea = "" if request.POST.get("tabla_linea") == None else request.POST.get("tabla_linea")
        responsabilidad = "" if request.POST.get("responsabilidad") == None else request.POST.get("responsabilidad")
        observacion = "" if request.POST.get("observacion") == None else request.POST.get("observacion")
        foto1 = "" if request.POST.get("foto1") == None else request.POST.get("foto1")
        foto2 = "" if request.POST.get("foto2") == None else request.POST.get("foto2")
        foto3 = "" if request.POST.get("foto3") == None else request.POST.get("foto3")
        params.add("tabla_ret", tabla_reg)
        params.add("codigo_ret", tabla_cod)
        params.add("linea_ret", tabla_linea)
        params.add("responsabilidad_ret", responsabilidad)
        params.add("observacion_ret", observacion)
        params.add("foto1_ret", foto1)
        params.add("foto2_ret", foto2)
        params.add("foto3_ret", foto3)

        eventos_aux = models.Evento.objects.filter(bus=interno, graffiti=False)
        eventos = []
        for evento in eventos_aux:
            if evento.estado_mtto == 'E':
                eventos.append(evento)
            elif timezone.now() - evento.ultima_reparacion.fecha_hora_reparacion < timedelta(days=3):
                print("Diferencia de Días>")
                print(timezone.now() - evento.ultima_reparacion.fecha_hora_reparacion)
                eventos.append(evento)
        params.add('eventos', eventos)

        eventos_graffiti = models.Evento.objects.filter(bus=interno, graffiti=True)
        params.add('eventos_graffiti', eventos_graffiti)
       
        return render(request, 'report_app/verificacion/registrar_evento.html', params.get())
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'El interno no es del patio del usuario actual!')

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('buscar_interno'))


@login_required(login_url="iniciar_sesion")
def save_evento(request, interno, nombre_completo):
    params = Parameters(request)

    if request.POST:
        responsabilidad = request.POST.get('responsabilidad')
        cod_operador = request.POST.get('cod_operador')

        params.add('conductor', models.Conductor.objects.get(nombre_completo=nombre_completo))


        conductor = None
        try:
            if cod_operador ==  "":
                cod_operador = 0000
            conductor = models.Conductor.objects.get(cod_operador=cod_operador)
            rut_input_conductor = None
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as NotFound:
            conductor = None
            rut_input_conductor = request.POST.get('rut_input_conductor')

        

        tabla = request.POST.get('tabla_reg')
        graffiti = False

        if responsabilidad == 'V':
            if request.POST.get('graffiti'):
                graffiti = True
        
        linea = request.POST.get('tabla_linea')
        observacion = request.POST.get('observacion')

        evento = models.Evento(
                responsabilidad=responsabilidad,
                cod_operador=cod_operador,
                conductor=conductor,
                nomnre_com=models.Conductor.objects.get(nombre_completo),
                sin_codigo=rut_input_conductor,
                tabla=tabla,
                usuario=params.getUsuario(),
                bus=models.Bus.objects.get(interno=interno),
                patio=params.getUsuario().patio,
                recorrido=linea,
                graffiti=graffiti
                )

        if evento.save():
            print('Evento Guardado Con Exito..!')
        dano = models.Dano(evento=evento, observacion=observacion)
        if dano.save():
            print('Daño guardado!')

        if request.FILES.get('foto1'):
            models.FotoDano(foto=request.FILES.get('foto1'), dano=dano).save()
            print("Foto 1 guardada para evento: " + str(dano.evento.id))
        
        if request.FILES.get('foto2'):
            models.FotoDano(foto=request.FILES.get('foto2'), dano=dano).save()
            print("Foto 2 guardada para evento: " + str(dano.evento.id))

        if request.FILES.get('foto3'):
            models.FotoDano(foto=request.FILES.get('foto3'), dano=dano).save()
            print("Foto 3 guardada para evento: " + str(dano.evento.id))

        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Ha sido añadido un evento con identificador: ' + str(evento.id))
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'NO SE AGREGO EVENTO.. Ocurrio un problema Interno...')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('buscar_interno'))
```

`Html`

```
<!-- Save Evento-->
            <form action="{% url 'save_evento' interno=bus.interno %}" id="guardar_evento" method="post"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="container ">
                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center transparent_background_detalle_interno">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas">TABLA</h3>
                                    <input type="tel" class="border rounded border-primary form-control" id="tabla_reg"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese la Tabla" minlength="2" maxlength="8" 
                                        name="tabla" value="{{tabla_ret}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas" name="avtivo">CÓDIGO OB </h3>
                                    <input type="tel" class="border rounded border-primary form-control" id="tabla_cod"
                                        placeholder="Código" minlength="1" maxlength="4" 
                                        name="cod_operador" value="{{codigo_ret}}">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info conducor_btn waves-effect waves-light col-7 btn_buscar_conductor"
                                     onclick="searchConductor()" type="button" id="btn_buscar_conductor">Buscar Conductor</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas">RESPONSABILIDAD</h3>
                                    <select class="bg-warning form-control form-control" id="select_responsabilidad"
                                        name="responsabilidad" required>
                                        <option value="" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "" %}selected{% endif %} disabled>
                                            Seleccione una responsabilidad
                                        </option>

                                        <option value="O" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "O" %}selected{% endif %}>
                                            Operaciones
                                        </option>

                                        <option value="V" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "V" %}selected{% endif %}>
                                            Vandalismo
                                        </option>

                                        <option value="M" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "M" %}selected{% endif %}>
                                            Mantenimiento
                                        </option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- <div class="col-md-5 m-3 p-3 rounded-lg rgba-stylish-strong" id="graffiti_section"
                            style="display: none;">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input class="custom-control-input" id="graffiti" type="checkbox" name="graffiti">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="graffiti">Tiene graffiti?</label>
                            </div>
                        </div> -->

                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas">LINEA DE RECORRIDO</h3>
                                    <input type="text" class="border rounded border-primary form-control"
                                        id="tabla_linea" placeholder="Ingrese la Linea" minlength="3" maxlength="10"
                                        name="tabla_linea" value="{{linea_ret}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row mt-4">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas">OBSERVACIÓN</h3>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="observacion" id="observacion"
                                        value="{{observacion_ret}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container p-3">
                    <h4 class="evento_detalle_title mt-2 mb-2">TOMAR FOTO</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="file" id="foto1" name="foto1"
                                accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif;capture=camera" class="input-foto"
                                onchange="detectFile(this, 1)" value="{{foto1_ret}}" required>
                            <label id="input_foto1" class="border rounded col-12 label-foto" for="foto1">
                                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro icon_base" id="icon_upload1"></i> Foto 1
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="file" id="foto2" name="foto2"
                                accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif;capture=camera" class="input-foto"
                                onchange="detectFile(this, 2)">
                            <label id="input_foto2" class="border rounded col-12 label-foto" for="foto2">
                                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro icon_base" id="icon_upload2"></i> Foto 2
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="file" id="foto3" name="foto3"
                                accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif;capture=camera" class="input-foto"
                                onchange="detectFile(this, 3)">
                            <label id="input_foto3" class="border rounded col-12 label-foto" for="foto3">
                                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro icon_base" id="icon_upload3"></i> Foto 3
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="container p-1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 btn_flota mb-1">
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-block" href="{% url 'buscar_interno' %}">Buscar otro interno</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 btn_flota mb-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">GUARDAR</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

`Urls`

```
path('registro/registro_evento/<int:interno>',views.registrar_evento, name="registrar_evento"),
path('registro/save_evento/<int:interno>', views.save_evento, name="save_evento"),
```